# PHP preg_replace word but not if there is certain characters preceding the word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace a word with PHP [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).
It should not replace the word if the characters **/>** exist before this word.

i.e.

this should be replaced if matched

```
$word = "foo";
```

this should not be replaced if matched

```
$word = "/>foo";
```

Comment: [Don't use regexes to manipulate html.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: What about "/>                     foo";? or "/> (newline)

foo";

Comment: Don't want to manipulate html. In my case it will alwaysbe />foo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you are ;-)

```
(?<!/>)foo
```

good luck

Comment: I tried your regex but seems to replace the test string "/>foo".

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: How did you try it? This is *the* correct answer. It might be helpful to add that in PHP, you need delimiters around the regex, so it'll look something like `$result = preg_replace('%(?<!/>)foo%', 'REPLACED', $subject);`

Comment: Did anyone try it in with PHP yet?

Comment: This is the correct answer, i got it working with @TimPietzcker suggestion

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: Sorry for the mix up, I'm a "regex-junkie" but not a PHP-pro :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($word[0] != '/' && $word[1] != '>') {
    $new_string = str_replace($word, $replace, $string);
}
```